# is EF 4.3.x requiring anything else than pure standard official .NET Framework 4?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

We are thinking to use the newly released EF 4.3.x

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx

does anybody know if this released piece of software requires anything not already officially released like .NET Framework 4.5 or similar? We are not allowed to include in our solution anything not already officially released and I am afraid if a beta or CTP version of any component is required I won't be able to deploy the application in the production servers (architecture and implementation governance in place...) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 4.3.1.0 works fine on my VPS running .NET 4 (not 4.5)
Its been in action for a few weeks now and nothing to report.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework 4.3 is compiled against the .NET Framework 4.0.  There is no requirement to have .NET Framework 4.5 in order to use EF 4.3, but it will work with it.

Please see the image below from [Red Gate's Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) which shows the "References" that the Entity Framework assembly is built against.  Although this screen-shot only shows the "Microsoft.CSharp" assembly highlighted, and the resulting version information in the bottom pane (`Version 4.0.0.0`), I can confirm that all of the referenced assemblies are `Version 4.0.0.0`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its .net 4 based at the moment, version 5 is better optimized for 4.5 but i think that under the scenes its still .net 4.